# Angular 8 Mat-Tables Dynamic Columns and Expanding Rows

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

First time posting here so please forgive any mistakes.

I'm working on an Angular 8 project with Angular Material libraries. It's a website that needs to be able to be viewed on mobile, so we're using media queries and flexlayout queries to handle this.

My question relates to Angular mat-tables.

I can get columns to dynamically show/hide using observables to check screen width. What I'd then like to do is have a check to see which columns were hidden, and display them when clicking on an expandable row.

Expandable rows are what I'm mostly having trouble implementing properly when combined with the show/hide columns.

Is there any documentation or examples out there, or any advice you could give me?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share some code or any fiddle, plunker link

Comment: Checkout this example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-responsive?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Comment: To clarify, it's just a standard mat-table as outlined here: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples                                                 The issue is that while the standard table has each column in its own ng-container with mat-header-cell and mat-cell, Angular's implementation of expandable rows is both pretty dense and has all columns under one container. The issue is that the only ways I've been able to hide/show columns relies on having each column separated into different containers. So I'm asking if there is a better implementation of expandable rows.